# How to prevent VLC Media Player from auto-closing after video end

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

My VLC Media Player started to **auto close** after the end of a video. It never did that before and it seems that the setting has been set after the last update.

I checked the settings but couldn't find anything. Anyone else has the same experience or knows how to fix it?

My VLC Media Player Version is `3.0.6 Vetinari`. I use `Windows 10` OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### My VLC Media Player started to auto close after the end of a video.

To prevent this untick "Quit at the end of playlist":

> - Click on "Media"on the tool bar at the top of VLC media player.
> - Click on "Quit at the end of playlist" to disable automatic shutdown of VLC player after video ending.
>
> [image]

Source [Fix: VLC player closes automatically after video ends | ValueStuffz](https://valuestuffz.blogspot.com/2016/07/fix-vlc-player-closes-automatically-after-video-ends.html)

On MacOS, this option is under `Playback`:

[image: mac_screenshot]

Comment: I did not expect that setting to be there :D. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For Mac: I have noticed that unchecking 'Quit after playback' refers to quitting VLC, not your movie. VLC itself does not close, but the video still closes after playing. I don't see a selection that allows it to stop on the last frame without doing something additional. I am using an M1 Macbook Air on Monterey (OS X 12.3.1) if that makes any difference with other peoples' results.

Comment: For my above Mac comment, I just found a commentary on VideoLan's bugtracker forum about this: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=95021

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line method of keeping the video live on a Mac. According to notes on the VLC forum, the behavior has changed. I am using am M1 Macbook Air in Fall 2022 on Mac OS X 12.3.1 Monterey.

> Source: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=95021

As I mentioned in a comment on DavidPostill's answer, unchecking 'Quit after Playback' on a Mac keeps VLC from closing, but the video still does close.

Someone at VideoLan (nickname: VLC_Help) on the forum mentioned the VideoLan wiki shows command line options to solve this however. The following of course assume your version of VLC was installed in the default location.

How to do it on a Mac:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --play-and-pause
```

You can add a command line 'vlc' alias for this purpose in your .bashrc or .zshrc for either shell you use with this alias:

```
alias vlc='/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --play-and-pause &'
```

How to do it in Windows (Tested in Windows 11):

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --play-and-pause
```

In windows, you can add the '--play-and-pause' argument in a shortcut like above to make it so you don't have to keep dropping to the command line.

**If you start VLC with that command line argument, it will keep the video open after playback but stopped on the last frame.**

For those of you who are unaware because you may not have used but one of them, Macs and PCs do different things whe closing applications, which is why this is a point.

Windows (usually) closes the complete app when it is finished.

Macs (and modern tablets and smartphone) usually close the current media/project within the app, but don't generally close the app itself. This makes it fast to load up later. So there is a difference between closing the video and closing the app that plays the video.

This is not unique to video player apps, but the generic regular methodology for most apps on these platforms.