# How to stop VLC Player from minimizing when video ends?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I'm trying to keep VLC player full-screened when a video ends. Currently, when it hits the end of a video, it will exit fullscreen and return to whatever state it was in before. Is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your question (or a similar one) has been answered here: [https://superuser.com/questions/1412810/how-to-prevent-vlc-media-player-from-auto-closing-after-video-end#:~:text=Click%20on%20%22Media%22on%20the,VLC%20player%20after%20video%20ending](https://superuser.com/questions/1412810/how-to-prevent-vlc-media-player-from-auto-closing-after-video-end#:%7E:text=Click%20on%20%22Media%22on%20the,VLC%20player%20after%20video%20ending).

So, two things:

1. To prevent this untick "Quit at the end of playlist":

- Click on "Media"on the tool bar at the top of VLC media player.
- Click on "Quit at the end of playlist" to disable automatic shutdown of VLC player after video ending.

I've read your post and the solution above, and they seem to me to be asking the same.  Apologies to you if I'm mistaken.

Also, it appears that the interface is not set up identically across different OS types.  MacOS/OS X seems to differ from Windows and/or Linux.

2. From my experience, VLC has a whole, wide and unsuspectedly rich (detailed) set of capabilities that are accessible from the command line:  https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Mac OS 14.2.1 and using VLC Version 3.0.20 Vetinari (Apple Silicon).

1. Open "Settings..."

[image: Open "Settings..."]

2. Click on "Video"

[image: Click on "Video"]

3. Click on "Show All"

[image: Click on "Show All"]

4. Click on "Playlist" from the left vertical list and then check "Play and pause"

[image: Click on "Playlist" from the left vertical list and then check "Play and pause"]

this was driving me crazy because the last scene is important to see